# Как добавить свой тип сборки в cmake?

Tags: cmake

Я хочу добавить свой тип сборки в cmake и вызывать cmake следующим образом:

`cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=mytype`

В CmakeLists.txt я добавил следующие строки:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-fPIC -o0 -g")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MYTYPE "-fPIC -o0 -g -m32)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-fPIC -o3)
```

Судя по [документации](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#How_can_I_extend_the_build_modes_with_a_custom_made_one_.3F). Этого достаточно но проект все равно компилируется с флагами `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG`.

Что мне еще нужно сделать?

Comment: Добавте url документации.